# Make it drop-down if more than 1 sub-menu?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, meanjs

I am working on a project with Mean JS and I am using the template offered by them at https://github.com/meanjs/mean .
Basically I want to do:

```
 if (more than 1 sub-menus)
         make it drop-down
    else 
       make just a button and if that button clicked take it to state of the sub menu.
```

A button on the navigation bar will be defined as drop-down. It will have 2 sub-menus. This main button will be visible to all types of user. However, only  1 sub-menu on the drop down will be visible to **general users**. All 2 sub-menus will be visible to the **admin users**. I want to define it as drop down, but if there is only **1 sub-menu**, don't show it as drop-down. When a user clicks on the main button it will take it to the page defined in the sub-menu.

Here is the code that is in the header.client.view.html (This is from the template, I have not change it.)

```
<nav class="collapse  navbar-collapse" collapse="!isCollapsed" role="navigation">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav" ng-if="menu.shouldRender(authentication.user);">
    <li ng-repeat="item in menu.items | orderBy: 'position'" ng-if="item.shouldRender(authentication.user);" ng-switch="item.type" ng-class="{ active: $state.includes(item.state), dropdown: item.type === 'dropdown' }" class="{{item.class}}" dropdown="item.type === 'dropdown'">
      <a ng-switch-when="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle role="button">{{::item.title}}&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul ng-switch-when="dropdown" class="dropdown-menu">
        <li ng-repeat="subitem in item.items | orderBy: 'position'" ng-if="subitem.shouldRender(authentication.user);" ui-sref-active="active">
          <a ui-sref="{{subitem.state}}" ng-bind="subitem.title"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <a ng-switch-default ui-sref="{{item.state}}" ng-bind="item.title"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Here is what goes in the articles.client.config.js

```
// Configuring the Articles module
angular.module('articles').run(['Menus',
  function(Menus) {
    // Add the articles dropdown item
    Menus.addMenuItem('topbar', {
      title: 'Blog',
      state: 'articles',
      type: 'dropdown',
      roles: ['*'],
      position: 1
    });

    // Add the dropdown list item
    Menus.addSubMenuItem('topbar', 'articles', {
      title: 'Visit Blog',
      state: 'articles.list',
      roles: ['user', 'admin']
    });

    // Add the dropdown create item
    Menus.addSubMenuItem('topbar', 'articles', {
      title: 'Create Blog Post',
      state: 'articles.create',
      roles: ['admin']
    });
  }
]);
```